# multiply values on median by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply

I have dataset

```
df=structure(list(SKU = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), stuff = c(8.85947691, 9.450108704, 10.0407405, 10.0407405, 
10.63137229, 11.22200409, 11.22200409, 11.81263588, 12.40326767, 
12.40326767, 12.40326767, 12.99389947, 13.58453126, 14.17516306, 
14.76579485, 15.94705844, 17.12832203, 17.71895382, 21.26274458, 
25.98779894, 63.19760196), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    acnumber = c(137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

The action column has only two values 0 and 1. 
As we can see there is 3 observations by stuff of 1 category and 18 obs by stuff of zero category.

I need
`-`Calculate median for the stuff  variable only for category 1 (it is equal to 25.98779894) without zeros.
As we can see  there are zeros between one, they need to be removed, as well as negative values, if they exist.
I.e, as if the dataset was like this:

```
structure(list(SKU = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), stuff = c(8.85947691, 9.450108704, 10.0407405, 10.0407405, 
10.63137229, 11.22200409, 11.22200409, 11.81263588, 12.40326767, 
12.40326767, 12.40326767, 12.99389947, 13.58453126, 14.17516306, 
14.76579485, 15.94705844, 17.12832203, 17.71895382, 21.26274458, 
25.98779894, 63.19760196), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), 
    acnumber = c(137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Also i need calculate the median for the last three observations by stuff variable for category 0, which go before the first one,
in our case it is 12,40326767

then subtract from the median for category 1 the median by category 0 and multiply by the number of one, in this case 3.

(25,98779894-12,40326767)*3=40,75359381

this solution

```
df %>%
  group_by(SKU,acnumber,year) %>%
  summarize(value = 3*(median(stuff[action==1]) - median(stuff[match(1,action)-3:1])),
            stuff=first(stuff),
            action = sum(action)) %>%
  select(SKU,stuff,action,acnumber,year,value)
```

by Moody_Mudskipper helped me

But!In this example, the number of ones by action was three , so we multiply by three,
but the number of ones can be greater than 3 or less than three.
how to multiply on real numbers of ones?
for example if we have 2 ones by action for stuff,then

```
summarize(value = 2*(median(stuff[action==1]) - median(stuff[match(1,action)-3:1])),
```

so that do not manually enter it each time.

the solution
`sum(df$action == 1)` is not suitable

```
summarize(value = sum(df$action == 1)*(median(stuff[action==1]) - median(stuff[match(1,action)-3:1])),
```

because it sums up all the ones  of dataset and then there is  incorrect multiplication.
Total count of ones=692 and this number multiplies

```
 summarize(value = 692*(median(stuff[action==1]) - median(stuff[match(1,action)-3:1])),
```

it is wrong
The multiplication of ones  must be for each particular group SKU,acnumber,year

```
111-23-2018 is first group has 3 ones
112-24-2018 is second group has 2 ones
```

and so on

How to do it correct?

Comment: to get the real number of ones by group use `sum(action == 1)` => you need to remove the `df$` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df%>%
   group_by(SKU,acnumber,year)%>%
   summarise(s=sum(action),k=which(action==1)[1],
            l=s*(median(stuff[action==1])-median(stuff[(k-s+1):k])))%>%
   data.frame()
    SKU acnumber year s  k        l
1 11202      137 2018 3 11 40.75359
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for how or why this answer resolves the problem in the question.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.